# Select max entries in a range in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, range, max

I have a salary column where I have to select between range of 10000 and 20000 and also the top rows of max salary.

Column I have:

```
25000
17000
17000
15000
14000
9000
```

Rows I want to select

```
17000
17000
17000
```

I can use top n rows but that will apply on to this column. What I want to do is, say if this column has 2 rows that has max salary, it would select 2, but if another column has 5 rows that has max salary like below, then it should select 5.
column I have:

```
24000
17000
17000
17000
17000
17000
15000
14000
9000
```

rows I want to select:

```
17000
17000
17000
17000
17000
```

my sql statement:

```
select max(salary)
from table
where salary between 10000 and 20000
order by salary desc;
```

This statements only returns 1 row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `TOP 1 WITH TIES` here:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES salary
FROM yourTable
WHERE salary BETWEEN 10000 AND 20000
ORDER BY salary DESC;
```